# Can't compare strings on array while looping

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm currently working on my final test on this semester in my uni. I think of making program that will compare words on an array. If there is a word that same with previous inputed words, program will end.

But i still can't figure my way to do that.

I've tried to change the j, i, and tweaking the strcmp function but still got no answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, i, j, ret;
    char kt[255][255];

    printf("\t\t\t\tPlayers: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("\t\t\t\tPlayer %d: ", i+1);
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", kt[i]);

        if(i==0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        for(j=i+1;j<a;j++)
        {
            ret=strcmp(kt[i],kt[j]);
            if(ret==0)
            {
                printf("\t\t\t\tPlayer %d, You lose!\n", j+1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\t\t\t\tEnd Game\n");
}
```

I expect the output would be like

```
Players: 4
Player 1: Test
Player 2: Test1
Player 3: Test
End Game
```

But what i get is

```
Players: 4
Player 1: Test
Player 2: Test1
Player 3: Test
Player 4: Test
End Game
```

Comment: So why exactly it should ask you for a player name three times, not four, as suggested by `a=4` and `for(i=0;i<a;i++)`?

Comment: `for(j=i+1;j<a;j++)` --> `for(j=0;j<i;j++)`

Comment: Also, I'd highly recommend reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), because it looks like a debugging issue, not C understanding issue.

Comment: @yeputons i'm trying to make a program that compare strings for each time user input the words, not after all the words has been inputed

Comment: @kiranBiradar Tried what you said and still doesn't work

Comment: @Madlest "compare strings" is not a specific problem with a specific solution. It also does not specify behavior of the program in any way; lots of programs compare strings somehow. There is no way for us to understand what does it mean for your program to "work". Expected output is helpful, but I don't understand how it should be derived from user's input, so I cannot check code against that.

Comment: @yeputons Thanks for your feedback though! This is my first time asking question, and also my English isn't that good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping wrong make it
`for(j=0;j<i;j++)` instead of `for(j=i+1;j<a;j++)`.

You also have to break the outer loop also

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, i, j, ret,flag=0;
    char kt[255][255];

    printf("\t\t\t\tPlayers: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("\t\t\t\tPlayer %d: ", i+1);
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", kt[i]);

        if(i==0)
        {
            continue;
        }

    // from j=0 to j< i to compare all previous entries
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            ret=strcmp(kt[i],kt[j]);
            if(ret==0)
            {
                printf("\t\t\t\tPlayer %d, You lose!\n", i+1);
                flag=1;  // using break will only break this loop so use flag to break next loop also
                break;
            }
        }
    if (flag==1){
        break;
    }
    }
    printf("\t\t\t\tEnd Game\n");
}
```

Comment: Please can someone give me the reason for a votedown at least so that i cant repeat the mistake for next time.

Comment: asuming that `printf("\t\t\t\tPlayer %d, You lose!\n", j+i+1);` is incorrect

Comment: i tested it and it came out to be correct if player 3 give repeated entry the it will print player 3 you lose|

Comment: @AmitojSingh I can not see why you have a downvote here - your answer basically nails his error.

Answer (score 0):

you should check from the first elem = 0 to current - i:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, i, j, ret;
    char kt[255][255];

    printf("\t\t\t\tPlayers: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("\t\t\t\tPlayer %d: ", i+1);
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", kt[i]);

        if(i==0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            ret=strcmp(kt[i],kt[j]);
            if(ret==0)
            {
                printf("\t\t\t\tPlayer %d, You lose!\n", i+1);
                goto exit;
            }
        }
    }

    exit:
    printf("\t\t\t\tEnd Game\n");
}
```

Comment: It works with this code, but the one that lose is the player who input the word first.